# Main report and sub report parameter in crystal report

Tags: crystal-reports

I’m going to use main report and sub report for showing some details.
Main report has InvoiceHeader Part and sub report has invoice detail part.
Invoice Header and invoice detail has 2 SPs.

SP_InvoiceHeader (Use for main report)

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[testSP1]
    @invnoH as varchar(20)
AS
BEGIN
    SELECT * FROM INV_HEADER WHERE INVNO=@invnoH
END
```

SP_InvoiceDetail (Use for sub Report)

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[testSP2]
    @invno as varchar(20)
AS
BEGIN
    SELECT * FROM INV_DETAIL WHERE INVNO=@invno
END
```

I create the main report and using Insert --> subreport I just add a sub report.
Both reports are used above SPs seperatly.

I just can pass a parameter to sub report using main report. This is the auto genetrated paramenter in sub report. (Pm-?@invnoH). It is showing another parameter in the sub report named @invno which also an auto generated parameter field based on the SP. But I cannot assign @invno to passing parameter.

Simply this equation is not working.
@invno = Pm-?@invnoH

How to pass main report parameter to stored procedure of the sub report? (Up to now I can show passed parameter in the sub report)

I'm using Crystal report version is 8.5

Comment: what is the problem with that comparision?

Comment: not a comparison. the SP of sub report is used a parameter. I want to assign main report value to sub report parameter.

Comment: instead of linking the `Pm-?@invnoH` in sub report link the parameter `@invnoH` with `@invno` during adding `sub report` links